# How to edit fields' display markup in a search view?

Tags: views, search

Working with searchapi and views. I have a view based on a search inWondering how to edit the markup for the fields? There's a general option to strip the markup elements, but how to control the markup for individual fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the field and drop down the "Style Settings" tab, here you can select an element and create new classes for the field, label or wrapper. You can also remove the css completely

Comment: This was wonky in the interface, looked like you could only strip the css out...